# Need to get username with file permissions

Tags: google-drive-api

When using `DriveService.Permission.List()`, you get a list of permissions for a specific file. But there is nothing there to uniquely identify the user account that has the permission. I found somewhere that one can add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` to the scopes list to achieve this, but this just gives me bad request with what would otherwise work.

Is there some way to get the usernames involved? I'm using a service account, as it is not possible to use the OAuth2 with copy pasting passwords...

I know that this can be done with Documents List API, but I don't want to use a deprecated API.

Answer (score 1):

You need to authorize for `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` and request for user profile by making the request below.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me
```

You can give it a try on API Explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.userinfo.v2.me.get

Comment: I'm using the .NET client. I added https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email to the scopes, but that just gives me bad request. I also added that line to the domain's "Manage API client access" scope line for the service account.

Do I need to add some service to the API console for my account?

And even then, how will this link a permission to a user account?

Comment: Is the ServiceAccount not enought to be able to accomplish this?

Comment: Apparently, I don't get more info with OAuth2...

So the question remains... 

I don't know how to do what you ask me to do with the .NET client.

Comment: What do you mean by a service account performing this action? If you're asking for service account's profile, it may behave differently. Please send code snippets when you receive bad requests.

Comment: I gave up and used the deprecated Documents list API, which solved the problem. But the question remains - How to do it with Google Drive API. @Burcu: I'm using a service account to access a domain's Drive. I want to see who has access to a given file. But I don't get a list of usernames, or any other way of identifying who has access.